# Integrate/embed java applet to openerp

Tags: java, javascript, applet, odoo

I need to integrate into my Openerp application a third party developed java applet to sign documents electronicaly. I tried to implement the following solution but it didn't work for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204467/applet-java-integration-with-openerp-odoo

I have the following java applet embeded into my xml view:

```
<openerp>
<data>

    <record id="view_firma_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">firma.form</field>
        <field name="model">x_firma</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Firma" version="7.0">

                <sheet>
                    <![CDATA[
                        <html>
                            <body>

                                <object id="signApplet" width="600" height="400" archive="ini4j-0.5.2-1.0.jar, icepdf-core-4.3.2-1.0.jar, icepdf-viewer-4.3.2-1.0.jar, AgesicFirmaApplet-AgesicFirmaApplet-2.5.jar, bcprov-jdk15-1.46-1.0.jar, commons-codec-1.2-1.0.jar, bcmail-jdk15-1.46-1.0.jar,log4j-1.2.14-1.0.jar,swing-layout-1.0.3-1.0.jar,commons-io-2.1-1.0.jar,bcprov-jdk15-1.46-1.0.jar,MITyCLibAPI-1.0.4-1.0.jar,MITyCLibCert-1.0.4-1.0.jar,MITyCLibXADES-1.0.4-1.0.jar,MITyCLibTSA-1.0.4-1.0.jar,jss-4.2.5-1.2.jar,commons-logging-1.1-1.0.jar, UserAgentUtils-1.2.4-1.0.jar,itextpdf-5.2.0-1.0.jar,bctsp-jdk15-1.46-1.0.jar,xmlsec-1.4.2-ADSI-1.0-1.0.jar">
                                    <param name="type"  value="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.5.0"/>
                                    <param name="java_arguments"  value="-Xmx128m"/>
                                    <param name="classloader_cache"  value="false"/>
                                    <param name="codebase"  value="http://server/appletFirmaAgesic">
                                    <param name="code"  value="uy.gub.agesic.firma.cliente.applet.SignApplet"/>
                                </object>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                    ]]>
                </sheet>


            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

When I try to execute that (it was installed with no problems), it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: <form string="Firma" version="7.0"><sheet>
```

Is there any way to do that or do I have to take another type of implementation.

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual issue you are facing? Is the applet running fine in standalone mode? If yes then it might be network issue. My suggestion is to cut down the number of jars in your class-path.

Comment: I've just updated the post with new info

Comment: Any suggestion about my proposal?

Comment: "it was installed with no problems and throws an error". What does it mean? Sorry @jack10bells, I am not aware of OpenERP. I gave you the suggestion on a generic base. If you are able to load the applet in simple html outside of your application then it might be an embedding issue with OpenERP.